# Kotlin: Map.get(key) vs Map.getValue(key)

Tags: kotlin

I was using `someMap.get(someKey)` in my code, which gave me an error saying `Please use !! or ?`. When I used `someMap.getValue(someKey)`, that error disappeared.

Can someone explain why we have 2 seemingly similar looking (but weirdly different) `get` function in `Map` class?

**UPDATE**

I guess it has something to do with exception, that `getValue` throws exception. But isnt it true that Kotlin doesnt have any exception throwing?

Comment: _But isnt it true that Kotlin doesnt have any exception throwing?_ - No, it's not true. Kotlin supports exceptions just like any other languages. _I guess it has something to do with exception_ - that's right, `get` [returns the value corresponding to the given key, or null if such a key is not present in the map](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/get.html), while `getValue` [returns the value for the given key or throws an exception if there is no such key in the map](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/get-value.html).

Comment: You can also read about it [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/map-operations.html#retrieving-keys-and-values).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In Kotlin they provide both methods for `Map`. `get(key)` returns the value if it exists or returns `null` if it doesn't, hence the nullable type. `getValue(key)` either returns the value for the key or throws an `Exception` if the key does not exist: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/get-value.html

If you are sure your map will contain the key, you can avoid using the nullable variant and use `getValue()`; if you don't know what the map contains, then use `get()`.